# How to display string HTML containing inline style tag from angular component

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, inline

I want to show a saved HTML containing inline style tag, from an angular component,
I have tried encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, but it's not working.

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-content',
  templateUrl: './page-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-content.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Get data from HTTP get in the ts component:

```
description=<p class="ql-direction-rtl ql-align-right" style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #236fa1;">test</span></strong></p>
```

Showing the data:
`<div [innerHtml]=description></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't allow you to directly pass styles into a variable because of security issues. So you have to explicitly tell it that your string is safe.

You do it as follows:

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'
```

....

```
export class AppComponent {
  description;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.description = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<p class="ql-direction-rtl ql-align-right" style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #236fa1;">test</span></strong></p>`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it is a string coming from HTTP get, I have just put the whole string here for the audience to notice it has an inline CSS style

Comment: @ShahabGhalamdoost Edited my answer. Hope it solves your issue :)